# python Find particular sub strings from content

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to fetch the particular format of the string from the content up to first occurrence of 5 digits. For example:

```
   s = """ Regular expressions are a powerful language 
            for matching text patterns. 
            This page gives a basic introduction 
            to regular expressions 56122 sufficient 
            for our Python exercises and shows 
            how regular expressions 65842 work 23 in Python."""
    print(re.findall(r"matching .* ? \d{5}", s, re.DOTALL))
```

However, I'm getting the following output:

```
['matching text patterns.
This page gives a basic introduction
to regular expressions 56122 sufficient
for our Python exercises and shows
how regular expressions 65842']
```

I would like this instead:

```
['matching text patterns.
    This page gives a basic introduction
    to regular expressions 56122']
```

Comment: `r"matching .*? \d{5}"` or `r"\bmatching .*? \d{5}(?!\d)"`

Comment: Try removing the spaces in your expression: "matching.*?\d+". This way the `*` becomes non-greedy rather than `?` matching an optional space.

Comment: @JohnSchroeder - Worked like a charm, Thank you